# How many $3$ digit different number that will be divisible by $5$ can be formed from the digit $0,2,3,4,5,6$ lying between $100$ and $1000$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, divisibility

> How many $3$ digit different number that will be divisible by $5$ can be formed from the digit $0,2,3,4,5,6$ lying between $100$ and $1000$.

---

My attempt:

Divisible by $5$ is possible only when unit digit will be either $0$ or $5$, means possibility for unit digit is $2$.

And possible number of choices for third place digit is $5$ (except $0$).

And possible number of choices for tenth place digit is $6$ (all).

So, total possible such numbers are $=5\times6\times2=60$ (answer).

Can you explain in formal/alternative way, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a formal way (though not much different than yours)...

---

**Add up the following:**

- The amount of numbers of the form $\underbrace{2,3,4,5,6}_{5\text{ options}}|\underbrace{0,2,3,4,5,6}_{6\text{ options}}|\underbrace{0}_{1\text{ option}}$
- The amount of numbers of the form $\underbrace{2,3,4,5,6}_{5\text{ options}}|\underbrace{0,2,3,4,5,6}_{6\text{ options}}|\underbrace{5}_{1\text{ option}}$

The total amount is $5\cdot6\cdot1+5\cdot6\cdot1=60$.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: You're welcome :)